# How to create jms-bridge between Wildfly and ApacheActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to create a jms-bridge from my WF 14.0.1.Final to the Artemis 2.6.3 standalone broker.

When I set a bridge like this:

```
        <jms-bridge name="HelloWorldQueue-jms-bridge" quality-of-service="DUPLICATES_OK" failure-retry-interval="5000" max-retries="-1" max-batch-size="10" max-batch-time="100">
            <source connection-factory="ConnectionFactory" destination="queue/HelloWorldQueue"/>
            <target connection-factory="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" destination="dynamicQueues/myQueue" user="admin" password="admin">
                <target-context>
                    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="tcp://localhost:5445?type=CF"/>
                </target-context>
            </target>
        </jms-bridge>
```

I get

```
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge] (Thread-98) AMQ342010: Failed to connect JMS Bridge N/A: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:236)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JNDIFactorySupport.createObject(JNDIFactorySupport.java:46)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JNDIConnectionFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory(JNDIConnectionFactoryFactory.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.createConnection(JMSBridgeImpl.java:961)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.setupJMSObjects(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1159)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.setupJMSObjectsWithRetry(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1258)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl.access$2600(JMSBridgeImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl$FailureHandler.run(JMSBridgeImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And there is no tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the JMS bridge just like any normal, remote JMS client. It uses the JMS and JNDI APIs to access any compliant broker. The only thing which needs to be configured are the JNDI environment parameters (e.g. things like the InitialContext factory, etc.) and the JNDI lookup names (i.e. for the connection factory and destination).

You're getting a failure when the bridge is trying to lookup the `connection-factory` from the bridge `target`. Here's how that's configured:

```
<target connection-factory="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" destination="dynamicQueues/myQueue" user="admin" password="admin">
    <target-context>
        <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
        <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="tcp://localhost:5445?type=CF"/>
    </target-context>
</target>
```

You've configured the `connection-factory` as `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`. However, that connection factory isn't available by default and you've not explicitly configured it in the `target-context` properties therefore you receive a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`. I recommend you simply use one of the connection factory names which is present by default, e.g. `ConnectionFactory`. Such a change would yield this configuration:

```
<target connection-factory="ConnectionFactory" destination="dynamicQueues/myQueue" user="admin" password="admin">
    <target-context>
        <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
        <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="tcp://localhost:5445?type=CF"/>
    </target-context>
</target>
```